# Android: Button to determine which activity to start?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a main activity with different grid sizes a player can choose to play a memory matching game. The idea is to have the player click the grid size he wants and then click the "Start" button which will determine which grid size the player has chosen AND THEN START THAT SPECIFIC ACTIVITY that pertains to the grid size.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="edu.uc.sumanth.preferences.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:text="2x2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2x2"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:text="4x4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button4x4"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:text="6x6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button6x6"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:text="Start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

I am trying to make use of the shared preferences concept, and I am new to Android.
Here is the code for the mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements View.OnClickListener {

public Button btn2x2;
public Button btn4x4;
public Button btn6x6;
public Button btnStart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn2x2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2x2);
    btn2x2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String gridA = btn2x2.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =   getSharedPreferences("gride-size", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("Size",gridA);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });

    btn4x4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4x4);
    btn4x4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String gridB = btn4x4.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("gride-size", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("Size",gridB);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });

    btn6x6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6x6);
    btn6x6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String gridC = btn6x6.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("gride-size", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("Size",gridC);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });

    btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button2x2){
            Intent twoByTwo = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_2x2.class);
            startActivity(twoByTwo);
        }
        else if(v.getId()==R.id.button4x4){
            Intent fourByFour = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_2x2.class);
            startActivity(fourByFour);
        }
        else if(v.getId() == R.id.button6x6){
            Intent sixBySix = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_2x2.class);
            startActivity(sixBySix);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Make Choice",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

}

My idea is to really determine which grid size the user choose, "WHEN THE USER CLICKS THE START BUTTON" and then start that activity. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Why have each option as a Button instead of using radio buttons https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html. So in the `onClick` of the start button you would get the selected value in the RadioGroup and then write that to SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use shared preferences to achieve this. You can just use a global flag in your activity to control what's launched. The best way to do this is using lambda's, but you need additional libraries to make it work.

The best way without lambda's to do this, is to create a generic listener for the onClick method, look at the view text (view.getText()) and then set a global variable flag, an enum or numeric switch. When the user clicks 'Start', you read from the global flag and determine what to launch.

```
private static int LAUNCH_FLAG = 0;
private static final int LAUNCH_2X2 = 1;
private static final int LAUNCH_4X4 = 2;
...

protected View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String text = ((Button) view).getText();
        if (text == "2x2") {
            LAUNCH_FLAG = LAUNCH_2X2;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're using lambda's you can simplify this on each button:

```
Button button2x2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
button2x2.setOnClickListener(view -> LAUNCH_FLAG = LAUNCH_2X2);
```

Then when you click play, just a switch statement:

```
switch (LAUNCH_FLAG) {
    case LAUNCH_2X2:
        Intent myIntent = ...
}
```